# React: microdata typeScope being pased weirdly

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I'm trying to set microdata to a p element contained in a parent component. When I set `itemScope=""` in the parent I don't get it in the p element in the dom, but if I set `itemScope` alone, it works as expected, although this means `itemScope={true}` as per React rules. `ItemScope` is a boolean attribute so as per HTML specs it should be empty string or canonical value when you want it to be considered true. What am I missing?

See fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rv9085ob/

```html
<!-- html -->
<div id="app"></div>
```

```js
// js
const SimpleComp = (props) => <p {...props}>ItemScope is [{JSON.stringify(props.itemScope)}]</p>;

const fragment = <div>
<SimpleComp itemScope="" />
<SimpleComp itemScope />
<SimpleComp itemScope={true} />
</div>;

ReactDOM.render(fragment, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Results in:

```html
<div>
  <p>ItemScope is [""]</p>
  <p itemscope="">ItemScope is [true]</p>
  <p itemscope="">ItemScope is [true]</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your requirement here? If you want itemscope to be boolean, pass it as <SimpleComp itemScope={true} /> or <SimpleComp itemScope={false} />

Comment: I need `itemscope=""` consistently across tags. I have another itemscope in the HTML tag of the document, and there I need to pass `itemScope=""` as it should. At the end what I want is to understand the rationale behind it. I don't see the reason why the tag is disappearing when the prop is empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this issue in the React Github repository. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13400

There is a PR open for this here, it seems to be ongoing - https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/13404

Comment: Thanks for the response. So long story short: react is understanding "" as falsy, _ergo_ removing the attribute. But only does that with whitelisted known attributes it understands as boolean, that's why in other tags where it doesn't know those attributes can go, React just passes the value along.